# Magento 2 warning installing time

Tags: magento2.3, error, fatal-error

```
Warning: require(/var/www/html/xyz/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/magentopwa/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/xyz/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/xyz/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/magentopwa/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

Comment: Please run the composer update command and after check

Answer (score 1):

Go to magento root dir (the place where composer or php bin/magento commands are executed)

run `composer clear-cache` and remove vendor - `rm -rf vendor`

after that perform `composer install`

than `php bin/magento se:up`

enjoy!